# Did `pwd` use to have a `-W` option?

Tags: sh, command-line-arguments, pwd

I am reviewing the source code for gitflow-avh (A VirtualHome edition), version 1.12.3, which ships with Git for Windows, version 2.31.1. I'm looking at lines 67-73 of the script [git-flow](https://github.com/jackfrued/gitflow-avh/blob/develop/git-flow).

```
*MINGW*)
    export GITFLOW_DIR=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
    pwd () {
        builtin pwd -W
    }
    ;;
*)
    # The sed expression here replaces all backslashes by forward slashes.
    # This helps our Windows users, while not bothering our Unix users.)
    export GITFLOW_DIR=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
    ;;
esac
```

What is the `-W` option? I'm only aware of `-L` and `-P` in bash. I'm fairly confident this is a "MINGW-ism", but I'm having trouble finding documentation online.

Does anyone know what the `-W` option does?

Comment: `through a dash (shell) script` How do you know it's a dash script? Might you give more information about the script and environment?

Comment: @KamilCuk Sure, of course. I'm actually reviewing the source code for `gitflow-avh` (A VirtualHome edition), version 1.12.3, which ships with Git for Windows, version 2.31.1. I'm looking at lines 67-73 of `https://github.com/jackfrued/gitflow-avh/blob/develop/git-flow`. In know it's dash because of the shebang.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'll update the question with this further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found this specifically has to do with `MSYS2`, as opposed to `MINGW`.

Per [MSYS2's website](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/How-does-MSYS2-differ-from-Cygwin/), "How does MSYS2 differ from Cygwin?":

[image: How_MSYS2_differs_from_Cygwin]

I had to run `MSYS2` itself to actually see what the `-W` option provided:

[image: MSYS2_pwd_w_option]

Answer (score 0):

In my "root" directory in Git Bash on Windows, `pwd` just gives me `/`.

But with `-W`, I get the real location:

```
$ pwd -W
C:/Program Files/Git
```

There's nothing on the man page for `pwd`, of course. Based on @A. Hendry's answer, I think I'll just alias `pwd` so that it always uses the `-W` option.